# how to get the (lat,lng) from the map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT] using google maps v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps

i want to get the map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT] 's (lat,lng)

so how to get it ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the map's `getBounds()` function and then the `getSouthWest()` on the result to return the latlng object for the bottom left corner of the map.